# Dropbox Python SDK installation error on Windows 7 (could not create 'build')

Tags: python, windows, sdk, dropbox

I was hoping to get some help.  I am trying to install the Python SDK for Dropbox on Windows 7 (have Python 2.7.3 installed).  Following the instructions in the readme file, I ran the following on the command prompt: "python setup.py install -f".  I received the following error.  Any thoughts?  Many thanks in advance.

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing dropbox_python_sdk.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to dropbox_python_sdk.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to dropbox_python_sdk.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'dropbox_python_sdk.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'dropbox_python_sdk.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win32\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build
error: could not create 'build': Cannot create a file when that file already exists
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry...I figured it out.  I guess I goofed something up in the download/extraction process as I started from scratch and it worked this time around.  8)