# Python Install of Dropbox SDK Fails

Tags: python, windows, sdk, python-2.7, dropbox

I have the same problem as here.

[Dropbox Python SDK installation error on Windows 7 (could not create 'build')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596744/dropbox-python-sdk-installation-error-on-windows-7-could-not-create-build)

The user didn't say how they fixed the issue (I have tried starting again, and reinstalling Python). I asked the user to elaborate and my post was deleted because I wasn't answering the question. Sorry, I'm new here. But re-posting seems counter intuitive to me.

Here goes...

I installed Python 2.7, then downloaded and tried to run setup.py of the Dropbox Python SDK.

It asked me to add the setuptools, so I did, and then tried to install the Dropbox setup.py from a CMD. After which I got the below...

```
C:\Python27\dropbox-python-sdk-1.5.1>setup.py install
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
writing dropbox_python_sdk.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to dropbox_python_sdk.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to dropbox_python_sdk.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'dropbox_python_sdk.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
writing manifest file 'dropbox_python_sdk.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build
error: could not create 'build': Cannot create a file when that file already exists

C:\Python27\dropbox-python-sdk-1.5.1>
```

What have I done wrong? I know it hasn't installed because the Dropbox module isn't there.

I'm using Windows Server 2008 64bit if that helps.

Comment: Add `--verbose`: `setup.py install --verbose`. Also, try to remove that `build` directory you see complaints about.

Comment: Yeah, probably os.remove not working because directory already exists... a little like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11625062/cant-remove-a-folder-with-os-remove-windowserror-error-5-access-is-denied

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Can you please elaborate on  
 
    "Add --verbose: setup.py install --verbose"

Comment: OK deleting the file "build" allowed me to complete the install. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Just had the very same issue, solved it that way. You may write your solution (delete build) as answer and mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer as per piokuc's comment. He/She did not mark an answer (for quite some time) so I am leaving it here for others to find.

"Remove the build directory you see complaints about. – piokuc"

I found that trying to install the Dropbox python module without 'Easy Install' if fails, leaving the Dropbox module install half finished. Simply delete the file in question and start again.